# In structured streaming checkpointing why offsets are not committed after foreachbatch

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

```
df
.writeStream
.trigger(Trigger.Once)
.option(checkpointKey, checkpointVal)
.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => }
```

This is the sample code I am running.
Observing that Structured streaming creates the offsets file at the beginning itself: checkpoints/offsets/3

Why does it not wait for the foreachBatch to complete and then write the offsets to checkpoint directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each micro batch is similar as one transaction.

1. When kafka source have new messages. The begin and end offsets for
   this microbatch will be writen to offsets folder.
2. Start processing.
3. If succeed, commit file will be writen into commits folder with same
   microbath id. If failed, will reexecute micro batch using the same
   offsets range.

Comment: Oh wow, I did look at content of commit file, dint realise the folder name is used :)